# Disabling automatic defragmentation with both SSD and HDD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, defragment

I have both a M2 SSD and a HDD in my computer. Now I've been trying to make my SSD faster, and found a video that said disabling automatic defragmentation would help me.

But since I have both, I would like to know if I have to disable automatic defragmentation completely to boost my SSD's performance, or if simply unchecking it from the drives is sufficient.

Thank you kindly!

Comment: Not sure is disabling fragmentation on a SSD makes it *faster*, but it should help extend the life of the drive. https://helpdeskgeek.com/help-desk/should-you-defrag-an-ssd/ , https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-10-alert-defragger-bug-defrags-ssd-drives-too-often/

Comment: No OS should be auto-defragging an SSD in this day & age.

Comment: @Tetsujin I agree, but can I just disable autodefragmentation completely, or should I leave it up for my SSD

Answer (score 1):

On a properly set up machine, the "defrag" option for an SSD is really Optimize. There is NO concept of defragging an SSD drive so do not tamper with that.

With regard to a Hard Drive, you can defrag a hard drive. But do NOT turn off defrag because automatic defrag will make the disk work better (= somewhat faster).

So the computer knows more than humans about keeping drives working quickly.

On an SSD you can run Optimize occasionally or set it to a schedule and that keeps the SSD healthy.

Comment: So, I can turn automatic defragmentation on but uncheck my SSD driver and I'll be fine?

Comment: Yes. You will be just fine doing that.

Comment: Alright! Thank you very much John

Comment: You can look in SU help to see how to mark answers you like